# Technologies extraction using URL of the website

Tags: 14.04, source-code

I would like to know whether is it possible to retrieve the technologies used to build a website just by having its URL using Ubuntu.
Say for example: if I have the URL:
https://www.wikipedia.org/

I want to know the technologies used to build this website.
The output would be :

```
PHP, HHVM, Vanish, AddThis and many others.
```

Is there any way to get this done faster?
Please, also remember that I have a file of list of website and I want to extract the web technologies of those websites and place them in a file just after the URL (Line by Line). Kindly, let me know if this is possible using Ubuntu command or any software on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please if anyone has any solution for my query. do let me know.

Comment: No it's not possible with a single command at least. You can use various web services like builtswith instead

Comment: @Anwar If it would have possible with a single command. I would have attempted that already. It is not possible, hence I am here to find a solution. If you have any please let me know. will be delighted to hear from you soon.

Comment: I personally think this is out of the scope of Ask Ubuntu. It's more related with programming because I believe  you need  to setup a complex environment to do so. What you use as OS is irrelevant in this case afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look into Kali or Parrot distributions for information collecting tools.

- **`nikto`** is one of them that I'd tried before and gives partial info. It is available is Ubuntu repository too.

  ```
  ~$ whatis nikto
  nikto (1)            - Scan web server for known vulnerabilities

  ~$ sudo apt-get install nikto
  ~$ sudo nikto -update
  ~$ nikto -Tuning b -h www.wikipedia.org
  - Nikto v2.1.5
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  + Target IP:          91.198.174.192
  + Target Hostname:    www.wikipedia.org
  + Target Port:        80
  + Start Time:         2016-11-14 09:22:30 (GMT1)
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  + Server: Varnish
  + IP address found in the 'x-client-ip' header. The IP is "105.107.105.185".
  + The anti-clickjacking X-Frame-Options header is not present.
  + Uncommon header 'x-client-ip' found, with contents: 105.107.105.185
  + Uncommon header 'x-cache' found, with contents: cp3041 int
  + Uncommon header 'x-varnish' found, with contents: 827655138
  + Uncommon header 'x-cache-status' found, with contents: int
  + Root page / redirects to: https://www.wikipedia.org/
  + No CGI Directories found (use '-C all' to force check all possible dirs)
  + Server banner has changed from 'Varnish' to 'mw1187.eqiad.wmnet' which may suggest a WAF, load balancer or proxy is in place
  + Cookie GeoIP created without the httponly flag
  + Retrieved via header: 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4
  + Retrieved x-powered-by header: HHVM/3.3.0-static
  + Server leaks inodes via ETags, header found with file /, fields: 0xW/3b2 0x5369720eefb07 
  + Uncommon header 'x-analytics' found, with contents: nocookies=1
  + Uncommon header 'backend-timing' found, with contents: D=236 t=1478774110870502
  + 269 items checked: 0 error(s) and 12 item(s) reported on remote host
  + End Time:           2016-11-14 09:23:21 (GMT1) (51 seconds)
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  + 1 host(s) tested
  ```
- **`whatweb`** is another tool. It has [non fixed bug
  (invalid multibyte escape error)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/whatweb/+bug/1464902) in Ubuntu.

  1. Open file of encoding auto-detection library for editing

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rchardet/universaldetector.rb
     ```
  2. Add `# encoding: US-ASCII`

  Even with this workaround above, the output is not clean as in Kali.

  ```
  ~$ whatis whatweb
  whatweb (1)          - Web scanner to identify what websites are running.

  ~$ whatweb www.wikipedia.org
  /usr/share/whatweb/lib/tld.rb:85: warning: key "2nd_level_registration" is duplicated and overwritten on line 85
  /usr/share/whatweb/lib/tld.rb:93: warning: key "2nd_level_registration" is duplicated and overwritten on line 93
  /usr/share/whatweb/lib/tld.rb:95: warning: key "2nd_level_registration" is duplicated and overwritten on line 95
  /usr/share/whatweb/plugins/wordpress.rb:436: warning: key "2.7-beta1" is duplicated and overwritten on line 453
  /usr/share/whatweb/lib/extend-http.rb:102:in `connect': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
  http://www.wikipedia.org [301] Cookies[WMF-Last-Access], Country[NETHERLANDS][NL], HTTPServer[Varnish], HttpOnly[WMF-Last-Access], IP[91.198.174.192], RedirectLocation[https://www.wikipedia.org/], UncommonHeaders[x-varnish,x-cache-status,x-client-ip], Varnish
  /usr/share/whatweb/lib/extend-http.rb:102:in `connect': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
  /usr/share/whatweb/lib/extend-http.rb:140:in `connect': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
  https://www.wikipedia.org/ [200] Cookies[GeoIP,WMF-Last-Access], Country[NETHERLANDS][NL], Email[Wikipedia-logo-v2@1.5x.png,Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png,Wikipedia_wordmark@1.5x.png,Wikipedia_wordmark@2x.png,sprite-bookshelf_icons@1.5x.png,sprite-bookshelf_icons@2x.png,sprite-project-logos@1.5x.png,sprite-project-logos@2x.png], HTML5, HTTPServer[mw1253.eqiad.wmnet], HttpOnly[WMF-Last-Access], IP[91.198.174.192], probably MediaWiki, Script, Title[Wikipedia], UncommonHeaders[backend-timing,x-varnish,x-cache-status,strict-transport-security,x-analytics,x-client-ip], Varnish, Via-Proxy[1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4], X-Powered-By[HHVM/3.3.0-static]
  ```

  Output from Kali:

  ```
  ~# whatweb https://www.wikipedia.org
  https://www.wikipedia.org [200 OK] Cookies[GeoIP,WMF-Last-Access], Country[NETHERLANDS][NL], Email[Wikipedia-logo-v2@1.5x.png,Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png,Wikipedia_wordmark@1.5x.png,Wikipedia_wordmark@2x.png,sprite-bookshelf_icons@1.5x.png,sprite-bookshelf_icons@2x.png,sprite-project-logos@1.5x.png,sprite-project-logos@2x.png], HTML5, HTTPServer[mw1253.eqiad.wmnet], HttpOnly[WMF-Last-Access], IP[91.198.174.192], probably MediaWiki, Script, Strict-Transport-Security[max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload], Title[Wikipedia], UncommonHeaders[backend-timing,x-varnish,x-cache-status,x-analytics,x-client-ip], Varnish, Via-Proxy[1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4, 1.1 varnish-v4], X-Powered-By[HHVM/3.3.0-static]
  ```

Comment: Helpful .. but still not what I am looking for. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JafferWilson,  :/ Almost same info from `whatweb www.wikipedia.org` if you may want to try it.

Comment: Please add this option to your answer also. I would like to know what you answer you have got. As I cannot see the output on my screen . May be some problem from my end.

Comment: @JafferWilson, I forget to mention that version of Ubuntu have some unfixed bug. Probably same case for you, I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 (last update). I have update the answer and included the output from my xubuntu and a kali virtualbox

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest that this is not really possible just with Ubuntu.

You can pull in data with a terminal browser like Lynx or a command like curl, but parsing it will be extremely time consuming.

This is the sort of thing you would need an extensive script to accomplish.  This would be a project of its own I think.

I've done some research, and similar questions have been asked before, but they are very few and far between.

You could use an online tool like https://builtwith.com to look up the details.

For example, it shows that techcrunch.com

- Uses NGINX as a webserver
- Uses SSL certs from Godaddy; Wordpress
- Shows an SSL Redirect
- Wordpress DNS
- Uses Postmark; Sailthru; Google Apps for Business and has SPF setup
- Is hosted by Wordpress.com
- Uses Wordpress VIP as it's CMS
- Uses a PHP interpreter
- Has a ton of analytics; advertisers and tracking
- Uses a lot of JS Libraries (all listed on the site) including things like jQuery and Backbone.js
- Uses AOL On; Tube Mogul and TidalTV for media

There is a lot of information there, you'll have to read through it yourself, but it's a great tool.

Hope that helps!

Good luck :)

This may also be a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on

There are other online tools listed in the above question as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but this is not what exactly I am expecting in terms of bounty answer. please can you add more references to your answer so I will be satisfied.

Comment: It's ok.  I'm not really interested in the bounty.  Just trying to be helpful.  There are honestly a ton of referenced sites and tools in the duplicate question I listed.  Well worth looking into :)